# Twig - cache json?

Tags: php, json, caching, twig, slim

I am using Slim Framework with Twig. The cache in Twig works ok when I output html. But it does not work when I output json:

```
$response->getBody()->write(json_encode($data));

return $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

My Twig setting in the Slim container:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => 'cache/',
));
```

Obviously it does not cache json at all. Is it possible to have Twig cached json then?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig's cache is required because you are writing files in a special language that needs translating to PHP. If you look at the files in the `cache/` directory, you'll see that they are your Twig files converted to PHP.

JSON is not a special language and PHP has built-in conversation from array to JSON (`json_encode`) and so there is no need to create a PHP version and hence there is no need for a `cache` directory for JSON output.

Finally, as an aside, in Slim, you can create a JSON output with:

```
return $response->withJson($data);
```